# convergence in L^{1} strong

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, sobolev-spaces

I search an proof of this lemma:
First,we have this definition: we tell that an sequence $f^{\epsilon}$ is equi integrable if 
$$\forall \eta, \exists \delta > 0, |E|\leq \delta \implies \displaystyle\int_{E} |f^{\epsilon}|dx \leq \eta$$

We have lemma: Let $\Omega$ an open bounded in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
If
$$
\begin{cases}
&f^{\epsilon} \to f \qquad \mbox{a.e. in} \quad \Omega\\
& f^{\epsilon},f \in L^1(\Omega)\\
& f^{\epsilon} \quad \mbox{bounded in} \quad L^1(\Omega)\\
& f^{\epsilon} \quad \mbox{is equi integrable}\\
\end{cases}
$$

then, $f^{\epsilon} \to f$ in $L^{1}(\Omega)$ strong.

To prove this lemma, we use the lemma Fatou with the Egorov theorem, but I haven't idea how we can use it to write the proof of this lemma.

Comment: Maybe you can refer to the proof of the Vitali Convergence Theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_convergence_theorem

Comment: Please don't deface your posts.

Answer (score 0):

Fix a positive $\eta$ and consider the corresponding $\delta$ in the definition of equi-integrability. By Egoroff's theorem, there exists some $A$ such that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{x\in A}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=0\quad\mbox{and}\quad \lambda(\Omega\setminus A)\lt \delta.$$
We thus obtain, using integrability of $f$, 
$$\int_\Omega|f_n-f|dx\leqslant  \lambda(\Omega)\sup_{x\in A}|f_n(x)-f(x)|
+2\eta.$$

Comment: Please, we don't use Fatou theorem?

Comment: No I didn't use it.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand how we obtain by integrability of $f$ : $\int_{\Omega}|f_n - f| \leq \lambda(\Omega) \sup|f_n - f| + 2 \eta$ ? And finally, $\eta$ will be tend to 0?

Comment: You are actually right, the fact that $\int_{A^c}|f|\leqslant \eta$ can be shown using Fatou's lemma.